# Dynamic flexbox navigation with links auto filling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a dynamic flexbox navigation depending on the height of the header. The links should automatically fill up from top to bottom and also always have the links vertically aligned in the middle. I know that this is possible and I have tried but failed knowing that I haven't mastered the flexbox quite yet.

**HTML:**

```
<header id="header">
  <div class="row collapse align-middle">
    <div class="medium-2 column" id="logo">
      <a href="https://domain.com">Logo Text</a>
    </div>

    <div class="medium-10 nav-wrap column">
      <nav class="nav-container">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/home">Hem</a></li>

          <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  display: flex;
}
#header > .row {
  padding: 0 20px;
  flex: auto;
}
#header .menu {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#header .menu li {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
#header .menu li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Here is an image of what I want to accomplish. Note that the red area the `<a>` element. I want to do this without using padding-top and padding-bottom and using flexbox instead.

[image]

Here is my code on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ludx4baj/

If someone maybe can help me out that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The links should automatically fill up from top to bottom and also always have the links vertically aligned in the middle.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
a {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h2>Logo Text</h2>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: If you're not sure what's being asked here, how can you provide an answer?

Comment: @cimmaon Thank you for your answer. I am sorry for a not so good question. I added some information to my question, including an image. I think you will understand my question a bit better.